# Can I play gta 5 online on my xbox one and play with my friend that has an Xbox 360

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to know so I can play with my bro

Answer (score 2):

No, reason being is because the Next-Generation version of Grand Theft Auto V & Online offers a lot more features than the Xbox-360. Therefore it's not possible to play with each other.